# How to stick UIView to top of UIWindow on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, ios8, uiwindow

I have a custom `UIView` which I want to stick to the top of the `UIWindow` even when interface orientation changes. Here is the my view in portrait orientation

[image]

The problem is that prior iOS 8 `UIWindow` coordinate system is not being changed with the orientation changes. So I need to make all the calculations by hand. 
The first thing is to change the transform of the `UIView`, which I do using this method

```
 -(CGFloat)angleForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    CGFloat angle;
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            angle = -M_PI /2.0;
            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            angle = M_PI /2.0;
            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight");
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            angle = M_PI;
            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown");
            break;

        default:
            angle = 0;
            NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait");
            break;

    }
    return  angle;
}
```

The second thing is to somehow map actual coordinate systems to UIWindow coordinate system, which stays the same.
So how should I calculate the frame of the custom `UIView` that even when the user rotates the view to other orientations I will have the same sized UIView sticked to the top centre of the screen? 
For instance this is how should the view look like in landscape

[image]

By the way this image is generated from iOS 8 version. For which I do the following

```
   self.frame =  CGRectMake(window.bounds.size/2-50, 0, 100, 100);
   CGFloat angle = [self angleForOrientation:orientation];
   self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

I need to do something similar to iOS 7. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Take a look at this project and at its code https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView

Comment: Thanks Andrea. That was first thing I've tried, but it didn't solve my case. May be I need to do some modifications on the source code.

Answer (score 1):

So Finally I figured out how to implement this.

I've created the following method to calculate the rect which will stick the view to top based on given bounds.

```
-(CGRect)getTopRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds orientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation window:(UIWindow *)window
{
    CGRect newRect;
    CGFloat statusBarHeight = [self getStatusBarHeight];
    CGSize screenSize = window.screen.bounds.size;
    CGFloat sW = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat sH = screenSize.height;
    CGFloat W = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat H = rect.size.height;
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            newRect = CGRectMake(statusBarHeight, (sH-W)/2, H,W);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            newRect =  CGRectMake(sW-H-statusBarHeight, (sH-W)/2, H,W);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            newRect =  CGRectMake((sW-W)/2, sH-H-statusBarHeight, W,H);
            break;
        default:
            newRect =  CGRectMake((sW-W)/2, statusBarHeight, W,H);
            break;
    }
    return newRect;
}
```

Then I just change the frame whenever orientation changes. 
So first I listen to Orientation changes

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarFrameOrOrientationChanged:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statusBarFrameOrOrientationChanged:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];
```

Then in the orientation change event handler and change the transform and the frame. (see my question to see the method which handles the transforms)

```
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
self.frame =  [self getTopRectForBounds:bounds orientation:orientation window:self.window]
CGFloat angle = [self angleForOrientation:orientation];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```